# How can I allow users to opt out of receiving e-mails with one-time login links?

Tags: emails, tokens, users, privatemsg

So I have been working on an update to my site to allow users to log in via one-time login links when they receive a Private Message.  Unfortunately, this kind of feature recently has [been in the news as a security issue](http://www.theverge.com/2013/8/20/4639934/login-instantly-okcupids-gaping-security-hole-that-gives-full-account-no-password), so I want to make sure that I give users a way to opt out.

The one-time login links are provided by the [Login One Time](https://drupal.org/project/login_one_time) module.  The e-mail notifications are provided by the [Privatemsg](https://drupal.org/project/privatemsg) module's *PM E-mail Notify* submodule, but ideally the solution would also work for e-mails sent by Rules, system e-mails, etc.

**How I add the login link**

In the *PM E-mail Notify* UI, in the body of the "You have received a new message" e-mail, I insert the following token:

`[privatemsg_message:recipient:login-one-time]`

and the whole link is:

`[privatemsg_message:recipient:login-one-time]?edit[name]=[privatemsg_message:recipient:mail]`

This provides the user with a one-time login link that looks like this:

> http://localhost:8888/en/login_one_time/1173/1377182743/RZCfB7uwKRB_bFVCeKPNwtOnDn2jFfGMO2FdaE_cpxI?destination=?edit[name]=useremail@example.com

(Note: the `?edit[name]=useremail@example.com` part is a query string for the [Prepopulate](https://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module which pre-fills the e-mail address on the login form in the event that the one-time login link has already been used.)

**What I want to do**

1. Add a boolean field to the user profile, "Do not send me one-time login links in my e-mail."
2. Somehow check the value of that field when sending e-mail notifications.

Is there a robust way to do this?  Here is what I have thought of so far:

- Instead of using Privatemsg to send the e-mail notifications, attempt to create the notifications in Rules.  But if I do this, then I cannot use any of the nice Privatemsg configuration settings (such as allowing users to choose when they would like to receive e-mails, e.g. every time they receive a message, only once per sender, etc.)
- I could somehow create a token that gives the one-time link if the user has not opted out or the regular link if the user has opted out. (I'm not really sure how to do this.)
- I could hack the *PM E-mail Notify* submodule to do what I want.

Ideally, I want to do the following: **if a user has opted out, I want to replace the one-time login link in any e-mail sent by the site with a link to the login form.**

Note: **My site is multilingual, and I am translating the e-mails sent with the site using the Variable and i18n modules.  So, any solution needs to be robust enough to handle multilingual e-mails.**

Comment: How exactly do you currently add those one time links? If you can explain that in more detail, it should be easier to expand that to cover this.

Comment: @Berdir Question updated.  I am using the  following token in the e-mail body: `[privatemsg_message:recipient:login-one-time]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is define your own token.

Start off with copying `login_one_time_token_info()` and `login_one_time_tokens()` into a custom module, change the hook names and rename the token to something like login-one-time-optional or whatever you prefer :)

Then, change the implementation of the hook_tokens() implementation so that you check the field on the $account and use either the existing function or `url('user/login', array('absolute' => TRUE))`. Keep in mind that existing users users might not have any data saved in that field, so add a default value, you might want to put something like this in a helper function:

```
if ($items = field_get_items('user', $account, 'your_settings_field')) {
  return (bool) $items[0]['value'];
}
else {
  // Default to use the one time login link.
  return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add the boolean field that you want to the user profile and then use hook_mail_alter or a similiar hook of the email module to check the value of that settings. (Make sure the value is added to the $user global so you could read it)

Comment: I could use `hook_mail_alter` to check the setting, but I still need to send the e-mail without the token if the user has opted out.

Comment: You can also alter the mail content and replace the link with the token to a static link to the login form.

Comment: Or, even better, you can add either link (or no link at all) from within hook_mail.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this.

Create a menu path some thing like `my-login/%user` and let all `my-login/%user/*` paths handled by this menu handler (may be with custom module, panel with php code content)

prefix the url with `my-login/%user` so that it looks like `my-login/[UID]/login_one_time/*`

on the menu handler, load the `%user` and check the boolean, if allowed, direct the request to `login_one_time/*` the actual path, or show the login block.

*You can use the [shorturl](https://drupal.org/project/shorturl) module tokens if that link looks lengthy.